# Unable to locate HighChart element by XPATH

Tags: selenium, xpath

**Problem :** 
I have following HTML structure(ScreenShot image link) and I want to find red colored element , I used following XPath ,

```
XPath = //div[@id="SpendByVendorPieChart"]/div[@id="highcharts-10"]/svg/g[@class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-tracker"]/path[@fill="#01BBAA"]
```

[HTML structure ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7laE.png)

XPath is correct, but it unable to find element ,it finds till node 2, from svg node it dont find,  but when I use CSS it finds this element. Is this problem with XPath which don't find complex element like Graphic element like PieChart, Bars.

Please help me in this case, I want to use XPath only as it gives lot of flexibility to write custom expressions.

Comment: You have missed out a '//' in front of the g tag, you have a single '/' instead. The g tag you are referring is two levels down from the svg tag and not the immediate level...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using the tags `svg`,`g` and `path` directly, change it as `[name()='svg']` ,`[name()='g']` and `[name()='path']`. Can you try the below xpath,

```
//div[@id="SpendByVendorPieChart"]/div[@id="highcharts-10"]/descenant::*[name()='g'][@class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-tracker"]/*[name()='path'][@fill="#01BBAA"]
```

Comment: Should've been (`*`s are missing) : `..../descenant::*[...]/*[...]`

Comment: @har07 Thanks!! updates the answer!!

Comment: Thank you @SudharsanSelvaraj as per your answer , problem solved after using " descenant " in XPath .

Comment: nice!! don't forget to accept the answer!!